# "ties de", "la de" aŭ "tiu(j)(n) de"

Tags: word-choice

Kiu el la jenaj frazoj estas ĝusta/malĝusta kaj kial?

1) Oni konas bestojn kaj ties danĝerojn, sed neniam **ties de** malsaĝulo.

2) Oni konas bestojn kaj ties danĝerojn, sed neniam **la de** malsaĝulo.

3) Oni konas bestojn kaj ties danĝerojn, sed neniam **tiujn de** malsaĝulo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nur la frazo 3) estas ĝusta.

En frazo 1) aperas *ties*, kiu ĉiam devas esti atribuaĵo, sen ajna vorto (eksplica ĉu subkomprenata), al kiu ĝi povus aparteni. Oni atendas ĉi tie objekton, ne esprimon de posedado.

En frazo 2) aperas artikolo sen substantivo aŭ alia vorto, kaj tio ne estas tolerata (eĉ se la substantivo estas subkomprenata).

La pronomo *tiu* en la tria frazo male rajtas aperi memstare aŭ kun subkomprenata substantivo, kaj sintakse *tiujn* ĉi tie havas la formon postulatan de la senco (objekto dependa de *konas*).